# Does docker consume CPU the way VMs do?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, benchmarking, metrics, netdata

Apart from looking at docker stats, I want to know how docker consumes physical CPU or where will it be classified between CPU User, CPU System and CPU Guest, etc, stats?

I am collecting metrics using [netdata](https://www.netdata.cloud/). I am looking at different types of workloads; this means just some prepackaged code that may contain a docker image because that is where some software is installed or databases that other parts of this workload or code in question depend on. Nedata returns a lot of metrics, for example,at the system level for CPU: you will have the following:

1. netdata.system.cpu.guest
2. netdata.system.cpu.guest_nice
3. netdata.system.cpu.idle
4. netdata.system.cpu.iowait
5. netdata.system.cpu.irq
6. netdata.system.cpu.nice
7. netdata.system.cpu.softirq
8. netdata.system.cpu.steal
9. netdata.system.cpu.system
10. netdata.system.cpu.user

If I am dealing with a VM, I know that the guest operating system cpu ticks values would be recorded as netdata.system.cpu.guest; I am trying to know where those for docker images would be recorded.

I have looked at docker stat and read over articles on the internet but I can't seem to find where these cpu values would be recorded.

This is important to me because I am trying to characterize these workloads, and I want to know things I shouldn't bother looking too much at with respect to characterization if the workloads do not have a docker image

Comment: Careful that you're not observing the host CPU load. Docker itself provides a layer of isolation from the host operating-system but won't neccessarily hide things like CPU load and so on.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I can see CPU load reported as 1,5 and 15 minutes averages but the problem is I am concerned about actual CPU utilization by docker. Just reported CPU as a feeler for how metrics collection is done.

Comment: This is probably better addressed at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) as this is not a programming question per-se.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. I will ask it there